# Using :first-letter pseudo-element on input button

Tags: css, button, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a button with only the first letter underlined.
Obviously I can not use tags , then I would realize it with css, by using the pseudo element :first-letter. It works very well in other contexts, but in button  doesn't work.
There are other solutions?

Comment: It seems to work in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/PEg6n/1/ What browser are you using?

Comment: I use "<input type='button' value="OK" [...]/>" and not "<button>OK</button>". With input type don't work...

code: <input type='button' value="OK" class="button1" />
css: .button1:first-letter {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't shared your code, I'll take a bold guess here.

You're using `<input type="button" value="Some Value">`, because there's no actual text inside (The displayed text comes from the `value=` attribue), `:first-letter` wouldn't work (because it works on the text inside of the element).

Instead, use `<button>Some Value</button>`, it should work fine.

Comment: Forgive me if I have not posted the code, I ask for help rarely!
I think the only solution is your. I will try to fit all of the code in this way.
thanks ;)