# Setting first letter capitalization in a button with CSS

Tags: css

I need to format elements' text string to lower case with a first letter capitalized. I am able to do it in div and even span, but changing it to a block element, but am not able to figure how to appluy to a button value.

```css
.textStr {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.textStr::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="textStr" value="CLICK ME">

<div class="textStr">
  THIS IS A DIV
</div>

<span class="textStr">
  text in span
</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using :first-letter pseudo-element on input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135832/using-first-letter-pseudo-element-on-input-button)

Comment: Yes, it does, which is the same answer I received below.

Comment: @santa Either mark this answered or flag your own post as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The `::first-letter` pseudo element is only available on non-void elements, so instead of an `input type="submit"` simply use a `button type="submit"`:

```css
.textStr {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.textStr::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="textStr">CLICK ME</button>

<div class="textStr">
  THIS IS A DIV
</div>

<span class="textStr">
  text in span
</span>
```

Comment: "Obviously" is pretty snarky lol

Comment: Obvious by the result the browser shows.

Comment: That changes nothing but

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion I got is using `button` instead...:

```css
button::first-letter, input::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button>some text</button>
<input type="button" value="some text"/>
```

I suppose it relates to having specified the text as an attribute in the case of `input`.